# A man with legs puzzle

Tags: riddle

A man has:

- 2 legs in the morning
- 3 legs in the afternoon
- 4 legs in the evening.

Explain how this can be. The numbers are not *completely* at random - these is some logic to it.

HINT

> Construction

Comment: Isn't it 4-2-3 in the Oedipus version?

Comment: @MarchHo; it might be, but this isn't that one

Comment: I always believe that men have 3 legs. Always.

Comment: Something to do with the positioning of the sun, and shadows?

Comment: projective geometry - like it - wrong

Comment: You're going to to have to make this puzzle less broad as there are clearly quite a few valid answers that you have stated are wrong.

Comment: @IanMacDonald; my thoughts exactly - there are some close calls, but not what I had in mind - i think i'll add a hint

Comment: If you want to give an answer, give it as an answer, not in the question.

Comment: @SeraphCheng: I think there might be a "unique" exception to that rule...

Comment: Hmm...any more hints?

Comment: @SeraphCheng; bananas, but its not relevant to this puzzle

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I don't get it.

Comment: @SeraphCheng; its a hint, but to a different puzzle

Comment: Maybe he's recently been to IKEA? Sometimes assembly takes a while.

Comment: **Construction**?  A man is building a table he started the night before.  It takes him all morning to build the third leg and all afternoon to complete the fourth leg.  But honestly, this puzzle is so broad there could be a bajillion solutions.  Could you make it more unique or accept someone's already posted answer?

Answer (score 15):

**A lateral thinking**

---

A man has:

2 legs in the morning

> His own 2 legs

3 legs in the afternoon

> He bought a fried drumstick chicken leg from the KFC in the noon. So he has 3 (his two + 1 chicken leg) legs in the afternoon.

4 legs in the evening.

> On his way home in the evening, he bought another chicken leg from KFC for his wife. So, now he has 4 (his 2 + 2 chicken legs) legs in the evening.

Comment: he didn't eat his own chicken leg in afternoon? If he wasn't hungry then why did he bought it in the first place?..:D

Comment: That third leg is in his stomach then (if he had it) :P

Comment: good,  but not exactly mine. i've added an edit to remove similar

Comment: @manshu because he became too busy to stop and eat the chicken leg, and figured he might as well wait until he was at home with his wife, at which point they could eat their chicken legs together. this is objectively the best possible answer to this question.

Comment: Now I'm hungry. Otherwise, great answer.

Answer (score 10):

A man has:

**2 legs in the morning:**

> (morning means his younger stage) `His own 2 legs`

**3 legs in the afternoon**

> (afternoon means his aged stage, he can't walk without his walking stick) His own 2 legs and a walking stick`

**4 legs in the evening.**

> (evening means he dies, now he lie in bed, bed has 4 legs) `Legs of bed`

Answer (score 6):

The man:

> is a distance runner/cyclist, and has entered a competition with various stages, split up into "legs".

2 legs in the morning, 3 legs in the afternoon, 4 legs in the evening:

> is simply his schedule for the race.

Comment: It could be a [Triathlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triathlon), 2 legs being running, 4 legs - swimming, but biking and 3 legs don't quite fit (his legs and "another thing")

Comment: that's good, but not what i had thought of

Comment: could be playing darts, but you'd be wrong

Answer (score 4):

2 legs in the morning

> His own 2 legs, walking around, going to work, ...

3 legs in the afternoon

> On the way home from work, he stops at the bar and has a few beers while sitting on a 3-legged bar stool.

4 legs in the evening

> Now he's tired, and he goes to bed. The bed has 4 legs.

Answer (score 3):

A man has:

2 legs in the morning:

> His own 2 legs

3 legs in the afternoon:

> He broke a leg and now he is walking with a crutch

4 legs in the evening:

> He broke another leg and now he is walking with two crutches

Comment: Poor guy... That's what I call a bad day